# Fresh installation seems to have no GUI, boots into tty1

Tags: system-installation, gui

I have an old Dell Latitude-Intel® Core™2 Duo 2.00 GHz laptop.

I have installed Ubuntu 16.04.5 Desktop (32-bit) and but got stuck at the terminal.

[image: Terminal]

It will not go further or into desktop screen. Did I install the wrong ISO or am I missing something?

[image: My PC specs can be seen here.]

Comment: What happens if you press ctrl + alt + f7?

Comment: If you're really running a 32 bit processor, you may be better of with Lubuntu - there are a couple of parameters that you will need to change to get it to run properly.  [https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PAE](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PAE)

Comment: My backup laptop has an Intel Core duo at 2 GHz. I think its a T5750 anyway it is 64 bit and has 4 GB ram. Are you sure your model is 32 bit? How much RAM do you have? Type `free -T` at the $ prompt you are seeing.

Comment: yes it is 21 bit os and 2GB ram

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix was talking about the processor, not the OS. We get it that you installed a 32bit version, but it can also probably support 64bit.

Comment: @pornsky I tried that and nothing happen

Comment: @charles green I following the instruction from the link but no different.

Comment: /Users/Mattes/Desktop/IMG_2056.JPG

Comment: You probably installed a server version. :-)))

Comment: I am not sure if this a server version. here is the file name i download it. lubuntu-17.04-desktop-i386.iso

Comment: The processor Intel Core2Duo does *not* need `forcepae`. And that computer should work with both 32-bit and 64-bit operating systems. But I agree with @CharlesGreen, that *Lubuntu would be better than standard Ubuntu* because the graphical desktop environment of Lubuntu has a lighter foot-print and will work much better with old hardware.

Comment: You say you installed 14.04 Desktop, but the photo says you installed 16.04, and in a comment you say you downloaded 17.04. Did you install the Server version of 16.04?

Comment: @Zanna Good Catch!  I've not installed any of the server versions myself, but this looks like the completion of a good boot.  I'll load up a server just-for-the-fun-of-it-all

Comment: @CharlesGreen thanks, that would be awesome! :) I agree, the system looks pleased with itself, not as if something's gone awry

Comment: @Zanna I think you were exactly correct - the screen above is exactly what I see when I boot an Ubuntu server....

Answer (score 4):

It appears that you have installed Ubuntu Server, version 16.04.3 and that this is not what you had intended.  The server versions of Ubuntu do not have a pre-installed desktop.

Based on what you have told us of your computer, I would suggest Lubuntu, a lighter version of Ubuntu for your computer, but regular Ubuntu or Ubuntu-Gnome should work as well.  You will need to download the 'desktop' versions of Ubuntu, and install one of them.

All of the Ubuntu versions can be found at http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/, and a guide to installing Ubuntu is on AskUbuntu at [How do I install Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)

Some helpful links:

[Lubuntu downloads](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/16.04.3/release/)

[Ubuntu downloads](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop)

[Ubuntu-Gnome downloads](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-gnome/releases/16.04.3/release/)